# mysql database and java connection in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am new to Ubuntu, I had written a simple code to connect to the DB and retrieve some data from the table. It works fine when I use the shell in SU mode whereas in the normal shell it is giving the exception "No Suitable driver found".

this is my classpath env Variable value $CLASSPATH

```
 bash: /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar: Permission denied
```

This is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class DBDemo
{
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/david","root","root");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from abc_tbl1");  
    while(rs.next())  
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));
    con.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```

Is this is the issue with the env variables or the user?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The issue is probably a "permissions" issue with the `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar` file, or directories on the path to the file. See https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: Even I cannot run the normal java program but it compiles well. what could be the issue with the env variables ?

Comment: How do you compile a java program? Are you using an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse or using terminal and `javac` to compile?

Comment: using terminal with javac and java.... its compiling any where but it is not executing anywhere in the system...

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Is it openjdk or oraclejdk?

Comment: its openjdk java version 8 in ubuntu 16.04